# How should be updated a backbone.js model after deleting an other related model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, real-time

I have a `contact resource` with a `linked photo`.

Both, `contacts/3` and `photos/56` are fetch from the server at startup.
I assume it is good to keep my backbone collections in memory
and avoid fetching from the server all the time.  I also keep my views
in the DOM as much time as I can for speed purposes.

When a user wants to delete the `photo/56`, from all the photos 
he has on the server, he can do it though the photo apps, I have 
to eventually update `contacts/3` locally in memory.

There is many solutions, however, what is the backbone traditional way
to handle this scenario and have coherent linked models on
the browsers ?

- Should I avoid keeping my models and views in memory and fetch them constantly ?
- Should I detect the impact on the related contact and request a sync on this element ?
- Should I have a notification resource to get those sorts of updates ?

Regards.

Comment: When you say that the user can delete a photo from the photo apps are you referring you a section of the backbone app that handles photos or a separate application?

Comment: For now, the deletion is initiated by an app (another view) in the same browser, so I think first interpretation is a must, althought, since I tagged this question 'realtime', I will eventually need to cover your second interpretation

Comment: For the first case you can tell your contacts collection to listen to the remove events on your photos collection when you bootstrap your application.

Comment: @ScottPuleo: ok for first interpretation , I understand that the backbone apps should manage internally as much as they can based on what they know (a removed event).  And for second interpretation ?

Comment: You have some options.  Checkout these posts:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11718301/how-to-do-polling-in-backbone-js  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657968/how-to-use-backbone-js-with-websockets-socket-io-nowjs

Comment: I am not fan of polling but it is the limitation of dealing with a request driven server.  Thanks.