# Backbone.js How to keep data in sync in view?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm modifying the Backbone.js example Todos app to be a location manager.

When you add a new "location" in the browser, the ruby backend grabs the POST data from the browser, and geocodes the address.  It then replaces the address the user typed in the browser with the Google-returned nicely formatted address, and then finally adds the new location to the database. Since I have not properly wired up Backbone to keep this data in sync in the view, the nicely formatted address does not show up until I refresh the page.

My goal is to have the nicely formatted address automatically show up right after the new location object is added to the database.

I saw the potential solution by Jason Stonebreaker here, but not sure where this code belongs: [Polling a Collection with Backbone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963324/polling-a-collection-with-backbone-js)

My code: https://gist.github.com/Lordnibbler/5331943

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had forgotten to have my JSON REST API return the newly created or updated Location object in JSON after POST or PUT data was sent to the server.  Having the POST/PUT endpoints return the current Location object in JSON allowed backbone to automatically update the attributes.